# Почему не работает цепочка css анимаций?

Tags: javascript, css

Если нажать на кнопку `in`, а затем на `in-out`, то второе звено второй анимации выполнено не будет. Почему и как это исправить?  Неужели перед добавлением новых классов старые не очищаются в следствии чего получается то что в примере?

```js
document.querySelector('.button-group').addEventListener('click', 
    event => {
        let id = event.target.classList.value;
        let rect = document.querySelector('.rect');

        if(id === "in"){
            rect.classList.add('zoom-in-animation');
        }else if(id === "in-out"){
            rect.classList.remove('zoom-in-animation');
            rect.classList.add('zoom-in-out-animation')
        }
    }
)
```

```css
.center {
    position: absolute;

    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.rect-control {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;

    border: 1px solid black;

    
}

.rect {
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;

    background: lightcoral;

    

    transform-origin: center center;
}

.zoom-in-animation {
    animation: zoom-in 1s linear 0s 1 normal running forwards;
}

.zoom-in-out-animation {
    animation-name: zoom-out, zoom-in;
    animation-duration: 1s, 1s;
    animation-delay: 0s, 1s;
}


@keyframes zoom-in {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@keyframes zoom-out {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="rect-control center"></div>
<div class="container center">
    <div class="rect"></div>
</div>
<div class="button-group">
    <button class="in">in</button>
    <button class="in-out">in-out</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй  вот так `if(~selector.className.indexOf('in')) {console.log('hasClass');}` или

```
if(selector.classList.contains('in')) {console.log('selector hasClass in');}
```

PS Почему название переменной id ?

Comment: но [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) это **не** массив

Comment: ok. псевдомассив.

Comment: На самом деле и не _псевдомассив_, тут уже локализаторы не могут в перевод. На самом деле это [live DOMTokenList collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) и с массивом весьма мало общего, практически ничего